# Inverted left & right stick axes in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, joystick, gamepad

I've faced a weird problem with SDL2.

```
case SDL_CONTROLLERAXISMOTION:
    switch (e->caxis.axis)
    {
    /* LEFT && RIGHT Stick Movement */
    case SDL_CONTROLLER_AXIS_LEFTY:
        puts("Y");
        break;
    /* UP && DOWN Stick Movement */
    case SDL_CONTROLLER_AXIS_LEFTX:
        puts("X");
        break;
    }
    break;
```

Using my Xbox 360 Controller on Windows 10, I just the move the left stick forward and backward which is in the y-axis logically. But it prints `X` instead.

There's no problem with my controller since it works as it should be with all other games.

I've also used some gamepad tools for debugging and the results are the **true** y and x axes directions.

What did I miss? It's the same with the right stick too.

Comment: Do you have the last SDL version?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I have the 2.0.8 version (latest). I can work with them this way but it's just confusing...